# How do you copy/paste or import/export VBA code from one spreadsheet to another?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have written some VBA code in an Excel Spreadsheet (Excel 2016).  I was working in a sample spreadsheet, and now I want to easily transplant my VBA code into the real spreadsheet.  Copying/pasting the command buttons doesn't carry over any of the code.  And I'd rather not do a whole bunch of manual copypasta.

I know that you can export a single module/class, but I have not found a way to export everything all at once.  Do I need custom vba code for this?  Some kind of add-on?  Or is there a process built into Excel somewhere that I missed?

I have a few userforms, modules; and a few buttons on a worksheet.  I could do it manually, but I'm worried about making mistakes in the future if I have to do it again.

The autosuggessted [question](https://superuser.com/questions/790604/move-worksheet-to-another-workbook-without-the-vba-code-but-keeping-the-colour), even though the title is 180 degrees from what I am looking, does not apply.  I tried to copy the worksheet to another spreadsheet, and the VBA code did not copy over.  The sheet and the buttons on the sheet did though.

**META**

While asking this question, I got an automated "This question appears subjective and is likely to be closed".  I assure you, this is not [subjective](http://www.diffen.com/difference/Objective_vs_Subjective), although it is probably a very n00b level question.

[image]

Comment: How many sheets you have in your real sheet? Generally it's easier and more safe to move the data to the file containing the macro then the other way.

Comment: Did you went into the VBA editor? (ALT-F11) the interface should allow you to save an entire project, which you can restore back later.

Comment: @lpchip that is what I am asking how to do.  That process would be a suitable answer, so since you are familiar with the process, can you make an answer out of that.  For example, include relevent menus, options, locations, etc.

Comment: It has been many years since I worked with VBA and I don't have excel on my pc at home. I have to check it out thursday at work.

Answer (score 1):

This is a procedure I wrote some time ago to move as much VBA as possible over to another workbook in the case that it became corrupted - feel free to tweak this as you see fit.

**Important note**: *For this to work, you need to have enabled access to the VBProject in your security settings. You also need to have the workbook you are copying from closed.*

---

**MORE Important note**: *This code will create a temporary directory and delete it when it's finished - please check all paths and names in the code to ensure that by some coincidence this isn't an existing folder on your system. I am not responsible for any lost files/data on your system as a result of running this code without checking properly.*

---

```
Sub CopyBrokenWorkbook() 

     '// This sub will create a duplicate workbook with the prefix "EXP_"
     '// and import all userforms & code modules from old workbook.
     '
     '// This sub requires access to the VBA Project Object Model, this option can
     '// be found in the trust center settings under "Macro Settings".


    Dim oldWB As Workbook, newWB As Workbook 
    Dim VBc As Variant 
    Dim exportFolder As String, VBcExt As String, Bill As String, _ 
    newWBPath As String, testFile As String, wbPass As String 
    Dim i As Integer 


     '//Set old workbook
    testFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xl*), *.xl*") 
    If LCase(testFile) = "false" Then Exit Sub 


    If MsgBox("Is this workbook password protected?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then _ 
    wbPass = InputBox("Please enter workbook password:") 


    On Error Resume Next 
    Set oldWB = Workbooks.Open(testFile, Password:=wbPass) 
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then 
        MsgBox "Incorrect workbook password, this macro will now stop.", vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, "Error" 
        Err.Clear 
        Set oldWB = Nothing 
        Exit Sub 
    End If 
    On Error Goto 0 


    If oldWB.Name = ThisWorkbook.Name Then 
        MsgBox "Cannot run sub on this workbook!", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Error" 
        Exit Sub 
    End If 


     '//Check VBA protection
    On Error Resume Next 
    If oldWB.VBProject.Protection <> 0 Then 
        If Err.Number = 1004 Then 
            Err.Clear 
            MsgBox "VBA Project Object Model is protected in " & oldWB.Name & vbCrLf _ 
            & vbCrLf & "Please remove this protection in Trust Centre to continue.", _ 
            vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, "Error" 

            oldWB.Close 
            Set oldWB = Nothing 
            Set newWB = Nothing 
            Exit Sub 
        Else 
            MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbExclamation, "Error" 
            oldWB.Close 
            Set oldWB = Nothing 
            Set newWB = Nothing 
            Err.Clear 
            Exit Sub 
        End If 

    End If 
    On Error Goto 0 


    Set newWB = Workbooks.Add 


     '//path to export folder
    exportFolder = oldWB.Path & "\ExportTest" 


     '//if export folder exists, remove all files, otherwise creaate the folder
    If CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").FolderExists(exportFolder) = True Then 
        On Error Resume Next 
        Kill exportFolder & "\*.*" 
        Err.Clear 
        On Error Goto 0 
    Else 
        MkDir exportFolder 
    End If 


     '//export all modules/class modules/userforms to folder
    For Each VBc In oldWB.VBProject.VBComponents 
        Select Case VBc.Type 
        Case 1 
            VBcExt = ".bas" 
        Case 2 
            VBcExt = ".cls" 
        Case 3 
            VBcExt = ".frm" 
        Case 100 
            VBcExt = "SKIP" 
        End Select 
        If Not VBcExt = "SKIP" Then VBc.Export exportFolder & "\" & VBc.Name & VBcExt 
    Next VBc 


     '//duplicate sheet count in new workbook
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False 
    Select Case oldWB.Sheets.Count 
    Case Is < 3 
        While newWB.Sheets.Count <> oldWB.Sheets.Count 
            newWB.Sheets(newWB.Sheets.Count).Delete 
        Wend 
    Case Is > 3 
        While newWB.Sheets.Count <> oldWB.Sheets.Count 
            newWB.Sheets.Add after:=newWB.Sheets.Count 
        Wend 
    End Select 
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True 


     '//duplicate sheet names in new workbook
    For i = 1 To Sheets.Count 
        newWB.Sheets(i).Name = oldWB.Sheets(i).Name 
    Next i 


     '//save new workbook with old workbook's attributes and "EXP_" prefix
    With oldWB 


        newWBPath = exportFolder & "\EXP_" & .Name 


        newWB.SaveAs newWBPath, .FileFormat 
    End With 


     '//import modules/class modules/userforms to new workbook
    For Each VBc In CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFolder(exportFolder).Files 
        Select Case LCase(Right(VBc.Name, 4)) 
        Case ".bas", ".frm", ".cls" 
            newWB.VBProject.VBComponents.Import exportFolder & "\" & VBc.Name 
        End Select 
    Next VBc 


     '//save new workbook
    newWB.Save 


     '//get pathname of old workbook for later
    Bill = oldWB.Path & "\" & oldWB.Name 


     '//close workbooks
    oldWB.Close False 
    newWB.Close False 


     '//release from memory
    Set oldWB = Nothing 
    Set newWB = Nothing 


     '//create an excuse to reference a cool film whilst removing old workbook
    '// Kill Bill <~~ ONLY UNCOMMENT THIS LINE IF YOU WANT TO DELETE ORIGINAL WORKBOOK! 


     '//move new workbook to old workbook directory
    CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFile(newWBPath).Move _ 
    Mid(Bill, 1, InStrRev(Bill, "\")) 

    On Error Resume Next 
    Kill exportFolder & "\*.*" 
    On Error Goto 0 


    RmDir exportFolder 


    MsgBox "Transfer complete, please re-apply any password protection to your new workbook.", _ 
    vbInformation, "Done" 

End Sub
```